# Abel's identity yielding inconsistent Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the ODE $$ y''(x)+4y'(x) = 0, $$
with solutions $y_1 = e^{-4x}$ and $\require{cancel} \cancel{y_2 = x}$, I seem to be getting an inconsistent result when computing the Wronskian.

On the one hand we have $$ W[y_1,y_2](x) = \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1 & y'_2 \end{vmatrix} = y_1y'_2-y'_1y_2 = e^{-4x}(1+4x)\ . $$

On the other hand, Abel's idenity states $$ W[y_1,y_2](x) = \exp\bigg(-\int \frac{a_1(x)}{a_2(x)}dx \bigg) = e^{-4x} $$
for the ODE $$ a_2(x)y''(x) + a_1(x)y'(x) + a_0(x)y(x) = 0 \ .$$

---

I have followed the steps in a proof of Abel's identity, in order to see where this inconsistency shows up.

The relation $$ \operatorname{\frac{dW}{dx}} = \frac{-a_1(x)}{a_2(x)} W $$
seems to hold if we substitute $W=y_1y'_2-y'_1y_2$. Hence, my surprise when I try to obtain the Wronksian $W$ itself using Abel's identity, giving $e^{-4x}$ instead of $e^{-4x}(1+4x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y_2(x)=x$ is not a solution: $y_2(x)=1$ is.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to G. Sassatelli's observation, suppose we have the ODE $$a_2(x)y''+a_1(x)y'=0.$$ Then by inspection the first solution is $y_1=1$ and the Wronksian is of the form $W(x)=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'=y_2'$. Hence
$$a_2(x)y''+a_1(x)y'=a_2(x)W'+a(x) W=0\implies \frac{d}{dx}\ln W(x)=-\frac{a_1(x)}{a_2(x)}$$
which is indeed Abel's identity.